# How to make high score list in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I'm making small android game. And i'm in trouble at the end of the project that i dont know how to make High Score List.

I want to make list with

1st - Point

2nd - Point

3rd - Point

I tried using SharedPreferences. My code:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(final_hard_android.this);
    Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("username", "<username goes here>");
    editor.putInt("score", point);
    editor.commit();
    String gameUsername = sp.getString("username", "default");
    int gameScore = sp.getInt("score", 0);
```

point is the result of the game!

But i dont understand, and dont know how to show this list on layer?

Please help.

Appreciate

Answer (score -2):

really!!
you can use a layout with 6 labels on it(for show points and ranks)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


   <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="1ST" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Points"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="2ND" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:text="Points"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="3RD" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="Points"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and call your layout in a activity for example:

```
setContentView(R.layout.test);
TextView lbl1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
lbl1.setText("1st your point");

TextView lbl2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
lbl2.setText("2nd your point");

TextView lbl3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
lbl3.setText("3rd your point");
```

Comment: you dont understand -.- i need java code..what should i do with xml..i know how to make xml